# Action not defined - ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 605

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.3

I'm getting the following error: ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 605: Action App\Http\Controllers\VehicleController@processLead not defined.

I've checked if the route exists by using the `command php artisan route:list` and it does.

routes\web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Http\Controllers\VehicleController;
use App\Http\Requests\ValidateLeadValues;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
Route::get('usedcars/', 'VehicleController@index');
Route::post('processLead/{id}', function ($id, ValidateLeadValues $leadValues, VehicleController $vehicleController)
{
    return $vehicleController->processLead($id, $leadValues);
})->where(['id' => '[0-9]+']);
```

I have the following inside my view file. The code is in my form's action and when I remove it, the page loads fine.

```
{{ action('VehicleController@processLead', ['id' => $vehicle->id]) }}
```

Comment: Did you update anything? Maybe you have wrong versions on different libraries.

Comment: Yes, I did a composer update. Everything was working before the update and now I'm receiving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have in the App\Http\Controllers\VehicleController a public method processLead?

Try changing the view to {{ url('processLead', [$vehicle->id]) }}

I think the problem occurs, because the route is not registered directly with the controller method.

Comment: I know you don't have enough points yet, but whenever you will get them, you should include this as a comment, not an answer

Comment: Yes, I have the public method processLead(). Changing action() to url() doesn't work because I'm guessing laravel doesn't know which controller to use for the url?

Comment: How do I register the route directly with the controller method? Is how I've registered it in my routes file not doing that already?

Comment: If it has worked before running composer update try to clear laravel's cache: php artisan route:clear;php artisan cache:clear;php artisan config:clear

Comment: I tried those commands and I'm still receiving the error. This is really perplexing because the only thing I've done since it was working is run composer update.

Comment: It works for me with the url function. Do you get the same error when you replace the route function with the url one?

Comment: I just tried it and it works. I'm not sure why I thought it wouldn't. Thanks a lot.